# I am trying to add an svg background and draw it on scroll in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, svg, sass

So here is my code in CSS for a background with a linear gradient on top of it and an SVG as the original background.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(
      to bottom left,
      rgba(34, 148, 82, 1),
      rgba(40, 121, 75, 0.4)
    ),
    url(../../assets/abc.svg);
  clip-path: polygon(
    100% 0%,
    0% 0%,
    0% 100%,
    1% 99.95%,
    2% 99.8%,
    3% 99.6%,
    4% 99.3%,
    5% 98.9%,
    6% 98.45%,
    7% 97.9%,
    8% 97.25%,
    9% 96.55%,
    10% 95.8%,
    11% 94.95%,
    12% 94.05%,
    13% 93.1%,
    14% 92.1%,
    15% 91.05%,
    16% 90%,
    17% 88.9%,
    18% 87.8%,
    19% 86.65%,
    20% 85.5%,
    21% 84.35%,
    22% 83.2%,
    23% 82.05%,
    24% 80.9%,
    25% 79.8%,
    26% 78.75%,
    27% 77.75%,
    28% 76.75%,
    29% 75.8%,
    30% 74.9%,
    31% 74.1%,
    32% 73.35%,
    33% 72.65%,
    34% 72.05%,
    35% 71.5%,
    36% 71.05%,
    37% 70.65%,
    38% 70.35%,
    39% 70.15%,
    40% 70.05%,
    41% 70%,
    42% 70.05%,
    43% 70.2%,
    44% 70.45%,
    45% 70.75%,
    46% 71.15%,
    47% 71.65%,
    48% 72.2%,
    49% 72.85%,
    50% 73.55%,
    51% 74.35%,
    52% 75.2%,
    53% 76.1%,
    54% 77.05%,
    55% 78.05%,
    56% 79.1%,
    57% 80.15%,
    58% 81.3%,
    59% 82.4%,
    60% 83.55%,
    61% 84.7%,
    62% 85.85%,
    63% 87%,
    64% 88.15%,
    65% 89.25%,
    66% 90.35%,
    67% 91.4%,
    68% 92.45%,
    69% 93.4%,
    70% 94.35%,
    71% 95.2%,
    72% 96.05%,
    73% 96.8%,
    74% 97.45%,
    75% 98.05%,
    76% 98.6%,
    77% 99.05%,
    78% 99.4%,
    79% 99.7%,
    80% 99.85%,
    81% 100%,
    82% 100%,
    83% 99.9%,
    84% 99.75%,
    85% 99.5%,
    86% 99.2%,
    87% 98.75%,
    88% 98.25%,
    89% 97.7%,
    90% 97.05%,
    91% 96.3%,
    92% 95.5%,
    93% 94.65%,
    94% 93.75%,
    95% 92.8%,
    96% 91.8%,
    97% 90.75%,
    98% 89.65%,
    99% 88.55%,
    100% 87.4%
  );
```

Now what I want to do with this is, I want to draw the SVG as I scroll down the page. Please keep in mind that the svg has paths only, but the paths are multiple. Hundreds of paths with no ids.

I'm using this in a component in Vue.js, and would really appreciate if anyone could help me sort this thing out.

Comment: What do you mean by "draw". Do you mean you want to "reveal" a background image as you scroll? Or are you literally trying to "draw" the lines of an svg image? If that latter, maybe look into [Green Sock's DrawSVG](https://greensock.com/drawsvg/), but note that it won't work with a background image - it would need to be an inline svg.

Comment: Yes something like that, but needs to be in the background, or if I add in line, can it stick to the background?

Comment: Ya, what you're looking for is css's `position: fixed`, that will cause any element in your HTML to be "stuck" to the background. Sorry, but your question is probably too vague to get a good answer. I think what you're trying to do will have nothing to do with the `clip-path` and you'll likely need to write some javascript to track the page scroll, and use a library like GreenSock to animate the strokes.